# HTML acting like style isn't referenced only in IE7 or IE Compatibility Mode

Tags: html, css

I have developed a website on CMS Made Simple, a common CMS for me to use. I never have a problem with IE7 but with this website, I am having this issue where it acts like the css isn't there. I have stared over the html and styles for over 2 hours, and I am sure it is something simple, but I can't figure it out. It is only IE7 or Compatability Mode for IE. Chrome/Firefox/Safari all work.

What could be causing the site to act like the style isn't linked up?

The website is
http://bradyinn.com/

Comment: I'd *guess* that it is falling over on [your syntax errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbradyinn.com%2Fstylesheet.php%3Fcssid%3D50&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en), but I don't have time to build a test case to prove it.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the info, I was focusing on the html, instead of the style. I went through the style, and it looks like my customer edited the stylesheet to modify the font size. Upon doing this she put in `"` into the stylesheet. If you will put together a answer, Ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You <del>have</del>had a rogue `"` character in your stylesheet. IE7 is not handling that correctly and fails to correctly parse anything past that point in the CSS.

A [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) will pick this  up.